# Can't go into normal mode in floating terrminal

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I am using toggleterm.nvim extension for creating floating terminals. I am also using lazyvim (https://www.lazyvim.org/) to get some default configurations.
I can create a new floating terminal using the keys: `<leader>ft` but I can't seem to able to get into normal mode once I open the floating terminal. In the default keymaps of lazyvim, `<esc><esc>` is mapped to `<C-\><C-n>` which puts into normal mode while the floating terminal is open. But pressing `<esc><esc>` doesn't do anything. Although pressing `<C-\><C-n>` does put me in normal mode.

I don't know why the keymap is not working. Any pointers? I am using iterm2 as terminal emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write "exit" in terminal or press ctrl + d